# STL Vector Swap Structure (C++)

Tags: c++, stdvector

What is the difference between

```
someVector.clear();
std::vector<int> ().swap(someVector);
```

and

```
someVector.clear();
std::vector<int> (someVector).swap(someVector);
```

Or do they accomplish the same thing?

Edit:
The goal is to free the memory associated with someVector.

Comment: They are equally pointless or you didn't put it clear. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both attempts to clear the vector and deallocated the storage it was using. Simply calling `clear()` is not guaranteed to do that; it may leave the vector's capacity as it was.

In the first case, the call to `clear` is pointless; the second line will swap the vector with an empty one, deallocating the memory afterwards.

In the second case, there's still no guarantee that memory will be deallocated; copying the vector may or may not preserve the capacity.

The way to do it is:

```
std::vector<int> ().swap(someVector);
```

In C++11, you could alternatively call `shrink_to_fit()` after `clear()`; but that also isn't guaranteed to release the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The first one creates an empty vector (default constructor) and swap it with someVector; the second one created a vector out of someVector (copy constructor) and swap it with someVector. No difference in your case, because you called clear()